# Return constant values in graphite in json format

Tags: graphite

How do we obtain a series of contant values in graphite. I have checked function `constantLine(x)`, however, it draws a constant line on the "graph". However, I would need the values in json format.

The function `Identity(t)`, returns `x(t) = t;`  what we need `y(t) = constant`.

Currently, it seems to me that we need to inject data points into graphite DB. Is there a way we can do without it.

```
[graphite web uri]/render?target=FUNC(x)&format=json.
```

*** Edit:
I have tried the constantLine(x) function
I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  *

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/views.py", line 104, in renderView
    seriesList = evaluateTarget(requestContext, target)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 10, in evaluateTarget
    result = evaluateTokens(requestContext, tokens)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 21, in evaluateTokens
    return evaluateTokens(requestContext, tokens.expression)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 27, in evaluateTokens
    func = SeriesFunctions[tokens.call.func]
KeyError: u'contantLine'
```

*

Answer (score 0):

`graphite.com/render/?target=constantLine(123.456)&format=json`

returns

`[{"target": "123.456", "datapoints": [[123.456, 1381399794]]}]`

Isn't this what you want? In case you are expecting graphite to return  pure `123.456`, you will have to edit the code and override how results are displayed.

1. Add a new function `customConstantLine(requestContext, value)` in [functions.py](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/master/webapp/graphite/render/functions.py)
2. Override the rendering class to print pure `123.456`, when the returning function is  `customConstantLine()`.

Heads-up: Your edit has to also account for cases wherein multiple targets are returned.

EDIT:

Patch your `functions.py`! In case you do not want to upgrade your Graphite add-

```
def constantLine(requestContext, value):
  start = timestamp( requestContext['startTime'] )
  end = timestamp( requestContext['endTime'] )
  step = (end - start) / 1.0
  series = TimeSeries(str(value), start, end, step, [value, value])
  return [series]
```

Comment: Hey i have an error when i use the same, which version of graphite are  you using?

Comment: 0.9.10. i have edited the answer to include a way around this.

Comment: Hi, there is a function threshold(20.1,"hello",color), this solves the issue, sadly again this does not work with &format=json; checked functions.py, its the same..

Comment: :/ Works with mine. i copied it and did paste it here.

Comment: re installing the webapp, The problem is in views.py.. not the functions.

Comment: What exactly was your issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43319/discussion-between-erbdex-and-vamsi-krishna)

Comment: Hey its django .. I have 1.3.. nd it needs 1.4, got the hint when it said problem with view